# End caps on UISlider

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uislider

I have a UISlider that I wan't to have a custom look for. I used the `setMaximumTrackImage:` method, but I have a bezel on the edge of my slider that I dont want the slider to be able to occupy. I tried setting the maximumValueImage, but that creates a gap between the slider and the cap like so:
[image]

How can I create a slider that has the end cap like above, but keep the slider from being able to slide over it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the background as a separate container view with greater width that the UISlider. Eemove your maximumTrackImage.

Comment: Ugh, that just seems messy. I suppose if there isn't another way to do this with the slider I'll have to do that.

Comment: I know what you mean, but none of UISlider's appearance properties are meant as a background view. A container is the right way.